# can't call an existing function from python shell

Tags: python, django

I have a python/django project, with a django app called `"testApp"`. under `"testApp"` I have a python file: `"hello.py"`. The file reads:

```
class Hello():
  def sayHello():
    print ("hello")
```

How can I activate the `sayHello` function from `python manage.py shell`

importing `"testApp"` doesn't help as calling `"Hello.sayHello()"` gives out an `undefined` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be def sayHello(self)?

Comment: how are u importing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the actual name you want to use. Just importing testApp won't do anything; you would need to do `from testApp.hello import Hello`.

Note also that since for some reason you have a class, `sayHello` is an instance method and therefore needs to accept the `self` parameter; also, you would need to instantiate the class before calling the method. However, Python is not Java, and there is absolutely no need for the Hello class to exist.